# python is hard crashing with a simple mp3 play call

Tags: python, audio, mp3, text-to-speech

The following code is hard crashing.  It was working fine then suddenly something changed and I don't know what, so I created this mini test app, and it's still crashing python in the call to play.  The try isn't getting caught, it's a hard crash of the python interpreter.  It does correctly play the audio, then crashes before returning.  Any help or guidance is appreciated, this is driving me crazy

I've tried running from a net new virt env and the host directly

I did install the following at the host level:
flac and ffmpeg

then in the virt env I've installed gtts, and pydub.  there are other things installed too, but I didn't think they would be the culprit, although if I just create a virt environment with only gttsand pydub I get an error 13 calling play, whereas my other virtenv doesn't give the error 13, but I don't know what's causing that.

The error 13 is on the path: C:\Users\larry\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpm6l7dmzm.wav

even though tts.save("output.mp3") puts the output.mp3 file into the local workind folder

---

{

```
from gtts import gTTS               # used to convert text back to audio
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

def text_to_speech(text):

    try:
        # Convert text to audio using gTTS and save it to a BytesIO object
        tts = gTTS(text)
        tts.save("output.mp3")

        # Load the saved MP3 file into an AudioSegment
        audio = AudioSegment.from_file("output.mp3", format="mp3")
        play(audio)   <---- hard crashing in this call



    except Exception as e:
        print (f"failed to play sound, {str(e)}")
        pass

text_to_speech("This is a test, this is only a test")
```

}